# java CORBA Server limiting the number of connection

Tags: java, oracle, corba, sun

I have a CORBA Server developed using Java (Oracle/Sun)... I do not know why, but the server is limiting the number of connection to 240. The application itself does not have any limitation... so i was wondering if the ORB itself can have some kind of properties to manage/limit this.

```
    Properties orbProps = new Properties();
    orbProps.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBServerId", Integer.toString(id));
    orbProps.put("com.sun.CORBA.POA.ORBPersistentServerPort", Integer.toString(port));

    orb = ORB.init(new String[]{}, orbProps);
```

Any help would be welcome :-)
Thanks.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 7 in the server side.

Comment: You can use jacorb. Can be set in jacorb.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glassfish you can adjust the pool of the ORB. There is fairly extensive documentation on this in the Glassfish manual.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abegt.html

Comment: Thanks fhossfel. I have checked that URL... and saw the "thread-pool-size"... but in the implementation which I have it's not Glassfish... it is pure oracle/sun java ORB...

Answer (score 0):

If your CORBA server is running on a Unix/Linux box, check the **ulimit** settings for the user account that is running it.

```
ulimit -n
```

This will tell you how many file handles the process can use.  If the value is quite low (for example, less than 2048), you can adjust it in your startup script or have your system administrator bump up the limit for all users.

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy. The value is quite high... see bellow:

$ ulimit -n
64000

Comment: Where are you seeing the 240 connection limit?  Do clients just stop connecting, or are you getting an org.omg.CORBA.IMP_LIMIT exception somewhere?

Comment: The client starts to get "org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE....
Checking the socket in the server side (netstat -an|grep "port") I can see that the number of connection is around 240 connections.